# Android : StartActivity + crash from xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having a problem in android for starting activity, i know the source but don't understand where is the problem. The problem come from a part of my xml activity, the API of reference is the 19th, here the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_mental_ex"
>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/clavier_effacer"
        android:id="@+id/clavier_effacer"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Button.Inset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clavier_container"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clavier_container" />

    // Here the culprit, all its child are constantly in red but i don't                  
    // understand why and android studio is not recognising either
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/clavier_container"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/top_clavier"
            >

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num5"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_5"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num6"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_6"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num7"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_7"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num8"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_8"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num9"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_9"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/mid_clavier"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num0"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_0"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num1"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_1"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num2"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num3"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_3"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_num4"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_num_4"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@id/mid_clavier"
            android:id="@+id/bot_clavier">

            <Button
                android:text="@string/clavier_send"
                android:id="@+id/clavier_send"                                                                             style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Button.Inset"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    // end of the culprit
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/mental_ex_container"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:text="Facteur1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mental_facteur1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_width="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mental_operande"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:layout_width="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="facteur2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mental_facteur2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mental_egal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="produit"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mental_produit"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/mental_timing"
        android:max="200"
        android:progress="30" />
```

Here the exception :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blabla.kiddomath/com.example.blabla.kiddomath.ActivityMentalEx}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that it does have a problem on a conversion, more precisely the dimension. Although I wonder what could be the problem with the number 18 :s. Have you tried to look in the android monitor the error line?

Answer (score 0):

I did, the error line come from the setContentView so when loading the xml, when i delete the culprit part it is working well